# Can not open zip file downloaded server to server with file_put_contents

Tags: php

I'm having some trouble getting a zip file downloaded from a remote server to another using file_put_contents()

This is currently from the api code that serves the binary data of the zip file:

```php
header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    //header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$update_filename."\"");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($update_path));
    ob_end_flush();
    @readfile($update_path);
    exit();
```

And this one is from the server saving the remote file:

```php
all curl request.....

$response = curl_exec($curl);
// some validation ....
// to simplify the process
file_put_contents($local_file, $response);
```

At this point the actual file is created, and if i open it using windows or winrar it does open just fine, but when i use ZipArchive:

```php
$file = '2019-07-07-update-1.0.4.9.zip';
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $zip->open($file);
        $zip->extractTo($directory);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r(error_get_last()); // Says it's an invalid zip object or damaged file.
        die;
```

I've tried some other configurations for the headers, but same problem, can't get to extract the file with php.

Comment: maybe `$file` is not found .. if you put this `if ($zip->open($file) ) { // the code } ` does it work ?

Comment: Yes, it does open the file (wich is weird) but it does not extract it :/

Comment: I’d start by checking if the byte size of the file that was downloaded to the second server via cURL, matches that of the original. If it does not, then try and comment out the line that sets the `Content-Length` in the first script, and test again.